# Вывод опции товара на странице сравнения

Tags: php, html, opencart, opencart2.0

Как я могу вывести в таблице на странице сравнения опцию под названием Основной материал (конкретнее - значение этой опции) в админ панеле opencart? Для списка в сравнении эта опция нужна. Нужна переменная? Застрял на этом моменте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Страница сравнения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Расширьте вопрос - покажите пожалуйста листинг кода, где вы пытаетесь получить необходимые значения и где вы застряли.

Comment: Кирилл, да я обязательно расширю описание и добавлю код, но сейчас работы выше крыши, некогда просто в данный момент